# MouseInput MouseEntered

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have two classes in java. The first one is responsible for rendering graphics. There is a

```
boolean show=false;
```

And then i have `MouseInput` class, everything works when pressing mouse, but when i set an event to `MouseEntered` implemented method it doesnt work.

```
public class MouseInput implements MouseListener {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();

        if (mx >= 300 && mx <= 400 && my >= 200 && my <= 250) {
            renderingClass.show = true;
        }

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

The boolean variable stays false but compiler doesnt return any mistake. What am I doing wrong please? Thanks.

Comment: Show detail code of class implementing the listener.

Comment: Ok, I did edit that

Comment: From your code, `mouseEntered` method does not `output` anything or execute any particular task for you to know that it is working. You are only assigning values to variables but not really performing any task.

Comment: In the rendering class I have a method that is checkong if show is true and if it is it performs its code. I have a tick method so it is rendering every tick and also checking for show

Comment: Can you try printing something in the `mouseEntered` method to see if the method is reached at all.

Comment: Try figuring where the problem is by placing `System.out.println("Area entered 1");` before `int mx = e.getX();` statement. And then `System.out.println("Area entered 2");` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Usually, a mouseEntered event occurs when the user moves the mouse inside the edge of the component.  Which means the MouseEvent’s x and/or y will be close to the component’s edges—that is, close to zero or close to the value of getWidth() or getHeight().  Unless your component’s size is 400 by 250 pixels, it is unlikely that the mouse pointer will be inside the area you’re testing.